# Making an Android radio station streaming app

Tags: android, internet-radio

Is there any straight-forward way to make an Android app that streams an online radio station? This radio station will be built by my company, so there exists no API or anything at the moment. Ideally I am looking to make an Android service so that users can listen to the radio while the application is running in the background. Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeking someone to develop this app for you? There are a lot of resources online for how to stream online radio stations to mobile devices. I know, because I found many of them when I wrote [just such an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fuegobeats.fuegobeatsradio) for a client.

Comment: No, I am planning to develop this myself. I was just asking first to see if there's a more straightforward way of doing it than what I've found from looking through stack overflow already.

Comment: Then basically your answer is to learn how to use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), as Prokash Sarkar notes in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31595326/2740621).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you asked leads to a broad answer. However here goes some tips for you.

For a streaming radio station you can create a steaming server or buy streaming hosting. There are some free software's available that can be installed in your server and use to produce audio streaming from tracks/audio input.

For free streaming software you can try,

http://www.shoutcast.com/BroadcastNow

http://icecast.org/

If you want to buy a streaming hosting service with pre-installed software like **SHOUTcast** try this,

http://www.shoutcheap.com/

Once you buy or host a radio station, you can connect to that station using a `http://ip_address:port_number` using Android `MediaPlayer`.